# How to use both fixed and stretchy CSS content

Tags: html, css, width, stretch

I'm trying to use both fixed-width and stretchy CSS content, similar to what is seen on [Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/). I assumed this would be easily achievable using min-width and max-width, however I am having trouble with sub-elements which are simply sticking to their minimum widths rather than stretching to the maximum.

A demo can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QDvtW/10/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need setting min/max width anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/UyZ6T/1/

The problem was basically  the `float: left;` on the stretch-1. You only need that on the fixed size part. It basically means: 'I am on the left now, and everything else takes the space to the right'. A div with float property tries to take as little space as possible, so that the rest can stretch.

Comment: would you also know how to stop the background colour of the sub-content from behaving strangely? It seems to span the entire width of the container. http://jsfiddle.net/CassS/

Comment: Right, haven't realized that. Seems like `overflow: auto;` on the stretch-1 does it. Unfortunately I can't really explain why. Maybe you have to test it with different browsers (http://jsfiddle.net/PJDCP/). By the way, if you want that sub-content only takes as much space as it needs, change it from `<div>` to `<span>`.

Comment: It seems to work OK in all up to date browsers, although I'll have to test it more later on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

remove `float:left` from `#stretch-1`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDvtW/20/)

Answer (score 0):

Your're essentially trying to create a fluid layout that contains fixed width elements, you need to set percentage widths on all of parent elements in order toget this to work like google calendar - change your css to the following

```
#container {
max-width:1280px;
min-width:260px;
    width:90%;
height:200px;
margin:auto;
background:#000;
}

#fixed-1 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
float:left;
background:#3fb44a;
}

#stretch-1 {
min-width:60px;
    width:20%;
height:200px;
float:left;
background:#c44d58;
}

#sub-content {
width:100%;
height:20px;
background:#4788ef;
}
```

​

Comment: That fiddle doesn't work as intended... The pink area should fill the remaining black space while still sitting next to the green box.

Comment: I see now that you need to omit the float left and set the width to auto if you don't want to set a specific width for the fluid box and have it take up all of that space - updated fiddle -[link](http://jsfiddle.net/yzPCN/4/)